# Problemas al traer un registro de una base de datos y mostrarlo con javascript en un pop

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda en un formulario y que por ejemplo el usuario agrega un id y que ese id sea almacenado en una variable y realice la búsqueda en la base de datos.

Por mostrar los datos en el JavaScript no tengo problemas. El problema es que como es un pop-up en tiempo real, no sé cómo enviar los datos del `input` a la búsqueda.

Coloco el código:

```js
// formulario
<form id="alerta2">
    <input type="text" id="tickeid" name="tickeid" placeholder="Buscar Tu ticket">
</form>
 // codigo javascript
 <script>   
  $("#alerta2").submit(function(){
    dialog.alert({
      title: "Busqueda Realizada:",
      message: "<?php echo $ticket_id; ?>",
        button: "Cerrar",
      animation: "fade",
      callback: function(value){
        console.log(value);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

</script>
```

Comment: En el dialog veo código `php` así que supongo que usas la función `eval` o algun derivado, lo cuál es inseguro, alguien podría modificar tu script y poner `<? php exec("shutdown now")?>` provocando que tu computador se apague, volviendo a la pregunta, la pregunta es demasiado ambigǘa por lo que recomendaría que editaras tu pregunta y fueras más específico.

Comment: eso lo soluciono despues. La pregunta es como guardo el valor del input en una variable, sin enviar los datos en el form ? porque como te digo es una ventana pop up

Comment: Puedes enviar por ajax y traes el resultado en el onsuccess.

Comment: Stack Snippet sólo debe usarse para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript que es ejecutable desde las preguntas o respuestas. Debido a que en este caso no lo es, he removido stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Lo cambie y ahora estoy enviando con ajax pero no logro que se envie lo del input y me muestre el pop up la informacion.
Este vendria siendo mi codigo del ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ejecutar(str){
    var xmlhttp;
   if(str==""){
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innertHTML="";
   return;
}

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {
    xmlhttp = new ActivexObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
   document.getElementById("alerta").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php?ticket="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }
</script>
```

mi codigo html

```html
<form id="alerta2" action="">
 <input type="text" id="tickets" onload="ejecutar(this.value)" placeholder="Buscar Tu ticket">
</form>
```

y este vendria siendo mi codigo del pop up

```js
 <script>   
  $("#alerta2").submit(function(){
    dialog.alert({
      title: "Busqueda Realizada:",
      message: "<div id='alerta'></div>",
        button: "Cerrar",
      animation: "fade",
      callback: function(value){
        console.log(value);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Stack Snippet sólo debe usarse para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript que es ejecutable desde las preguntas o respuestas. Debido a que en este caso no lo es, he removido los stack snippets.